# replacing certain pattern with html div

Tags: java, regex

I am very weak in `regex` and i think the task i have been assigned requires `regex`.
suppose i have following string `#B#Objectives:#B#We aimed to review how personality characteristics contribute to the onset, maintenance or modulation of.#B#Method:#B#The databases Medline and PsychINFO were examined from 1967 to 2012 to`.

Now what my requirement is to replace `#B#anystring#B#` with `<div class="format">anystring</div>`.

I think `regex` is required but i have no idea what the regex would be.

Please give any suggestion.

**updated**

```
String regex="#B#";
String textFormated = text.replaceAll(regex,"<div class='formated'>");
System.out.println(textFormated);
```

this is what i tried till now.It just replaces `#B#` with `<div class='formated'>` but there is slight complication in adding end of div.The end of div should be added if `:#B#` is found.But how these both regex can be used together.

Comment: What have you done already? Any code you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("#B#(.*?)#B#", "<div class=\"format\">$1</div>");
```

`.*?` is reluctant qualifier. It means, that it matches as few characters as possible (posibly zero) up to the next `#B#`.

Comment: thnks but can you tell me whats difference between using $1 and $2 as used by @Rakesh Chouhan

Comment: The number is the number of expression in parentheses. $0 is the entire match, $1 is the first parentheses submatch etc. $1 is correct in my case, $2 is correct in @Rakesh Chouhan's case. His solution is correct too, but if there is no text between #B#, #B# will go to the output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, this will help you

```
String givenData ="asdfasdfa#B#anystring#B#asdfasdfasdfas";
String pattern = "(#B#)(.+?)(#B#)";
String result = givenData.replaceAll(pattern, "<div class='format'>$2</div>");
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: The capturing group for `#B#` are redundant...